# Rethrown exception in overridden method not rethrowing

Tags: scala, spray-json

I'm overriding a method in spray-json in order to catch an exception it throws.  In one particular case I want to add special handling, but otherwise I want to rethrow the original exception.

But the exception isn't rethrowing.

```
object MyObject extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    override def fromField[T](value: JsValue, fieldName: String)(implicit reader: JsonReader[T]) = {
    try {
      super.fromField(value, fieldName)(reader)
    } catch {
      case e: DeserializationException =>
        if (reader.isInstanceOf[SafeListFormat[_]]) EmptyList.asInstanceOf[T]
        else deserializationError("Object is missing required member '" + fieldName + "'", e)
    }
  }
}
```

The deserializationError in spray-json:  https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/package.scala

The method I'm overriding is `fromField` in here:  https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/ProductFormats.scala

In debug mode I can see the original exception being caught, and my `else` case "rethrowing" the error, and even the deserializationError method being called in spray-json's library.  But even through the DeserializationException is a RuntimeException the overridden method doesn't terminate.

I had wondered if there was something about deferred execution of the deserializationError method.  But I even tried changing my exception handler from calling deserializationError to a simple `throw e` and that didnt work either.

What's going on here?

PS. I dont *think* this is specific to spray-json really, but is probably something interesting I dont know about scala.  But I kept the example as a real world as possible just in case it is something particular to the way my overridden method is called by the spray-json library code.

**EDIT:**  Raised same question with spray-user forum:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/YXtY6VyIVGk

Comment: Try to put the return type explicitly. I've seen some weird behavior in which an overridden version of a method infers a different type causing issues. Especially here since the type to be returned will be inferred from the if/else case.

Comment: Sadly, no luck.  I added the return type T but the (undesired) behaviour is still the same unfortunately

Comment: It seem ok to me to be honest. So here go a few random observations:

Comment: yeah, it seemed okay to me too.  which is why i had to raise the SO question :) I'm pretty new to Scala and between Futures, lazy execution and inferred types I often find something surprising (yet interesting).  This one is completely baffling.  I'll try your suggestions below in case it gives me any new leads.  Thanks for your responses though, hoping it brings to light something helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seem ok to me to be honest. So here go a few random observations (too long to put as comments):

1. Call `super.fromField[T]`, right now you are not passing the `T` param. When things are weird, try to make everything explicit.
2. You can try functional error handling:

   ```
   Try(super.fromField(value, fieldName)(reader)).recover {  
     case e: DeserializationException if (reader.isInstanceOf[SafeListFormat[_]]) => EmptyList.asInstanceOf[T]
     case t: Exception => throw t
   }.get
   ```
3. Note how I made the if part of the pattern match, doing that might help you insulate the problem.
4. I find it weird that your method does not terminate. You should probably try reducing the example to something very simple and start adding complexity little by little and see where it breaks.

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, with no luck.  There must be something interesting in the fact that this overridden method is called from Spray's library that makes it behave differently than expected.  I did notice one strange thing: If I take out the case statement completely I get different behaviour again.  I'll edit the question to add more information in case it's a clue, but now i'm starting to think I need to raise this in the Spray users forum.  Thanks for your replies.

Comment: It turns out that that if I throw any other RuntimeException other than a DeserialisationException then the method throws it correctly.  So now I'm wrapping the DSE with my own exception and I get the behaviour I need.  
I knocked together a minimal test app using the latest spray-json libraries in Akka which helped track down the problem.  I raised the question with Akka (since Spray is now part of Akka) [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/b-aYoZ-1H4A) but no luck with a reply.  I guess the "why" will remain a mystery.  But at least I have a way forward now.